# 'children' prop expects type 'string' which requires multiple children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, jsx

I'm not 100% sure how to ask this question.

I'm working on a tutorial and currently building a couple of components.

I have a folder within my components folder called LoadingComponent with a file called index.tsx, and I am receiving the below error:

[image]

Here is the whole file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody } from 'reactstrap';
import CenterPiece from '../CenterPiece';

export interface ILoadingProps {
    dotType?: string;
    children: string;
}

export const Loading: React.FunctionComponent<ILoadingProps> = (props) => {
    const { children, dotType } = props;

    return (
        <div className="text-center">
            <div className="stage">
                <div className={dotType} />
            </div>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

Loading.defaultProps = {
    dotType: 'dot-bricks'
};

export interface ILoadingComponentProps {
    card?: boolean;
    dotType?: string;
    children: string;
}

export const LoadingComponent: React.FunctionComponent<ILoadingComponentProps> = (props) => {
    const { card, children, dotType } = props;

    if (card) {
        return (
            <CenterPiece> <-- **** error pointing here ***
                <Card>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Loading dotType={dotType}>{children}</Loading>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </CenterPiece>
        );
    }

    return <Loading dotType={dotType}>{children}</Loading>;
};

LoadingComponent.defaultProps = {
    card: true,
    dotType: 'dot-bricks'
};

export default LoadingComponent;
```

The above file imports from another folder within components called CenterPiece and has a file called index.tsx file.  Here is that file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';

export interface ICenterPieceProps {
  children: string;  <-- **** I think this is the issue ****
}

const CenterPiece: React.FunctionComponent<ICenterPieceProps> = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <Container fluid className="p-0">
      <Container
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: '50%',
          top: '50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
          WebkitTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
        }}
        className="d-flex justify-content-center"
      />
        {children}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CenterPiece;
```

I'm not what I did wrong.  The tutorial did not specify that the ICenterPieceProp required multiple children.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Which component has the error?

Comment: @UmbQbify - the error is in the LoadingComponent. The first set of code above.

Comment: Yeah that "file" has error, but exactly which component has the error? You are not passing children prop to the `<CenterPiece />` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely you want children type to be string for `ICenterPieceProps` because you want to be able to pass more JSX within `CenterPiece` render. You can change string to `React.ReactNode` or `JSX.Element`

Comment: This appears to have worked.  Most of my background was working with JQuery, so I'm trying to learn React, but I gotta say, I don't remember this many updates with JQuery when compared to React.  It's a little frustrating.  Thank you for your answer.